# How does adding GROUP BY make this query more efficient?

Tags: mysql

I don't understand mysql's EXPLAIN output for the following two queries.

In the first query mysql has to select 1238264 records first:

```
explain select
    count(distinct utc.id)
from
    user_to_company utc
inner join
    users u
        on utc.user_id=u.id
where
    u.is_removed=false
order by
    utc.user_id asc limit 20;

+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref                             | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u      | ALL  | PRIMARY                    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                            | 1238264 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | utc    | ref  | user_id,FKF513E0271C2D1677 | user_id | 8       | u.id                            |       1 | Using index
```

In the second query, a `GROUP BY` was added which makes mysql to select only 20 records:

```
explain select
    count(distinct utc.id)
from
    user_to_company utc
inner join
    users u
        on utc.user_id=u.id
where
    u.is_removed=false
group by
    utc.user_id
order by
    utc.user_id asc limit 20;

+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type   | possible_keys              | key                | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | utc  | index  | user_id,FKF513E0271C2D1677 | FKF513E0271C2D1677   | 8       | NULL                    |   20 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                    | PRIMARY              | 8       | utc.user_id             |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+----------------------------+--------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
```

For more info, there are 1333194 records in the users table and 1327768 records in user_to_company table.

How does adding the `GROUP BY` make mysql select only 20 records in the first pass?

Comment: What is your first query *supposed* to be doing?  It only returns one row which is the total distinct count of `utc.id` that meets the `where` condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query has to read all the data to find all the values of `utc.id`.  It returns only one row, which is a summary for the whole table.  So, it has to generate all the data.

The second query is producing a separate total for each `utc.user_id`.  You have a `limit` clause and an index on `utc.user_id`.  MySQL is, apparently, smart enough to recognize that it can go to the index to get the first 20 values of `utc.user_id`.  It uses these to generate the counts.

I am surprised that MySQL is smart enough to do this (although the logic is documented pretty well [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html)).  But it makes perfect sense that the second query can be optimized this way where the first one cannot be.

Comment: How come MYSQL knows to use the index to get the first 20 values for the second query but not the first?

Comment: @Glide . . . The first query only returns *1* row, because of the aggregation function in the `select` clause.  The calculation for this row requires all the data in the table, because it is a `count(distinct)`.